# Why so many instances of ASP.NET Development Server?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am debugging a large web application solution, with the main web application project as a single startup project, configured to use IIS for debugging.  Whenever I run this application inside Visual Studio 2010, I still get multiple instances (sometimes over 15) of the  ASP.NET Development Server starting up as well.  Why does this occur?

Comment: This answer is going to be interesting :)

Answer (score 37):

Visual Studio has a setting in every Web Project's properties by default to start the development server when you are debugging. This enables, for example, a web project which contains Web Services to be available when you've selected a client web site or application to start.

If you do not want this behaviour follow these steps:

1. Select the web project
2. Open the "Properties" window by pressing `F4`
3. Change the `Always Start When Debugging` value to `False`
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for any other web projects in your solution

Source: ['"Always Start When Debugging" – Preventing multiple Visual Studio Development Servers from starting' by by Kevin Rintoul](http://blog.geocortex.com/2010/06/04/always-start-when-debugging-preventing-multiple-visual-studio-development-servers-from-starting/)

Comment: This is great. It's been driving me nuts for ages now.

Comment: @EricJ. I can see why it is like that. The Project Properties sheet configures properties contained within the project file itself (build configs etc) however the F4 properties are how Visual Studio treats the project. Slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

A [simple solution](https://gist.github.com/rsenna/4176866) if you have many web projects in the same solution: from the Package Manager console:

```
get-project -all | %{ $_.Properties | ?{ $_.Name -eq "WebApplication.StartWebServerOnDebug" } | %{ $_.Value = $False} }
```

This will change all web projects `Always Start When Debugging` setting to false with a single command.

Answer (score 0):

My setup is similar to yours (except I use CassiniDev ( http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/ ))

Go to all your secondary sites project properties : click "use Custom Web Server", set something in "Server Url" (for exemple http://your-iis-server:your_port/your_project, but it may be even invalid)..

This will prevent the automatic startup of Cassini for the secondary web sites.

Leave your main site in the original configuration.